# Paragraph ended before \@xnthm was complete

Tags: formatting, miktex, texstudio

I am writing lecture notes and I have started my tex file as follows:
NB: I am using Texstudio and miktex on a mac

code:

```
% !TeX spellcheck = fr_FR
\documentclass[12pt, twoside]{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts, amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french,english]{babel}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Théorème}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemme}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollaire}
\newtheorem{proposition[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{property}[theorem]{Propriété}
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remarque}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Définition}
\newtheorem{notation}{Notation}
\newtheorem{proof}{Preuve}

\textheight=8.88in \textwidth=6.7in
\oddsidemargin=0.15in \evensidemargin=0.19in
\voffset=-0.9truecm \hoffset=-0.6truecm \allowdisplaybreaks
\linespread{1.4}
\title{\textbf{\Large {Inégalités Intégrales}}}
\date{31 Octobre 2022}
\author{Farai Nechikwira}

\begin{document}
\maketitle{Chapitre 1: Inegalite integrale lineaire} 

1. Integrale de type Gronwall
\begin{theorem}
...
\end{theorem}
```

However I get the following error, `Paragraph ended before \@xnthm was complete.` on line 16. Line 16 is a blank like that is below the last \newtheorem declaration.

Removing that blank lines results in no errors but my title seems do dissapear when I compile. What could be the problem?

Comment: there is closing brace missing after `proposition`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems with your code.

The main one is a missing brace:

```
\newtheorem{proposition[theorem]{Proposition}
```

should be

```
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
```

But if your document is in French, as witnessed by the environments' names, you should do

```
\usepackage[english,french]{babel}
```

With your code, the main language would be English.

You also don't want `\newtheorem{proof}{Preuve}`, but rather

```
\setlocalecaption{french}{proof}{Preuve}
```

or, if you're running an older LaTeX release,

```
\addto\captionsfrench{\renewcommand{\proofname}{Preuve}}
```

Don't set “by hand” the page parameters: use the `geometry` package. Most important is not to set `\voffset` and `\hoffset`.

```
\documentclass[12pt, twoside]{book}
\usepackage{amsfonts, amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,french]{babel}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Théorème}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemme}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollaire}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{property}[theorem]{Propriété}
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remarque}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Définition}
\newtheorem{notation}{Notation}

\setlocalecaption{french}{proof}{Preuve}

%\textheight=8.88in \textwidth=6.7in
%\oddsidemargin=0.15in \evensidemargin=0.19in
%\voffset=-0.9truecm \hoffset=-0.6truecm

\allowdisplaybreaks

\linespread{1.4}

\title{\textbf{\Large {Inégalités Intégrales}}}
\date{31 Octobre 2022}
\author{Farai Nechikwira}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\chapter{Inegalité integrale linéaire}

\section{Integrale de type Gronwall}

\begin{theorem}
...
\end{theorem}

\begin{proof}
...
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

See the line

```
\newtheorem{proposition[theorem]{Proposition}
```

it is missing a `}`. Should be

```
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
```

Additionally you cannot define a theorem called `proof` as `amsthm` already defines an environment of that name.

Thirdly: I'd suggest using the `geometry` package to set the margins instead of manually like that.

Comment: I removed the ```\newtheorem{proof}{Preuve}```but now my proofs are written Proof instead of the french word Preuve

Comment: Removing the english lan in package resolved this

Comment: @Abel please read on on how `babel` works. The last language listed it the active one.